# md-paginator how i can get the next or prev click event

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to get the next button click  event any idea how I can make it

```
<md-paginator [length]="length"
    [pageSize]="pageSize"
    [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
    (page)="pageEvent = $event"
    (selectChange)="onPaginateChange($event)">   <---------  not working
</md-paginator>
```

Comment: Use `(page)` attribute instead. The `(selectChange)` attribute is only for `<md-select>`. [More info](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:**

Material changed their tags in recent verisons. Use `<mat-paginator>` isntead of `<md-paginator>`.

```
<mat-paginator [length]="length"
               [pageSize]="pageSize"
               [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
               (page)="pageEvent = $event; onPaginateChange($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```

**Original:**

Add your `onPaginateChange($event)` function to the `(page)` event.

```
<md-paginator [length]="length"
              [pageSize]="pageSize"
              [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
              (page)="pageEvent = $event; onPaginateChange($event)">
</md-paginator>
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/8van3R9RLJ1pJPIaWm28?p=preview)

Comment: While `pageEvent = $event` makes sense in the example context of your plunker, it's worth noting that it is not necessary to get the `onPaginateChange` callback to work

Comment: Too bad you can't figure out which button is pressed (first, previous, next or last)..

Comment: does the `(page)` works with `mat-paginator` or is there something new?